# I am making an android app that involves creating a text file. How do i specify the path where I want it to appear?

Tags: java, android, path, uri

I am new to android development, I think that something is wrong with the `Uri built = Uri.parse("/storage/sdcard0/Download/");`, but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package com.example.ecobinary;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CREATE_FILE = 1;
    private void createFile(Uri pickerInitialUri) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "testing.txt");

        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final Button execute_button = findViewById(R.id.execute_button);
        execute_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri built = Uri.parse("/storage/sdcard0/Download/");
                createFile(built);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: We do not usually use a `Uri` for direct filesystem access. Also, you do not have access to that location on modern devices, and there is no guarantee that the user has that location (removable storage). https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage is the entry point in the documentation for on-device storage options. You might also wish to read [this blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and [this blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html).

Comment: Your initial uri is irrelevant. Implement onActivityResult and use the uri selected by the user.